# Call function on submit of ajax form

Tags: jquery, ajaxform

I'm using the ajaxForm.js to make an ajax image upload.

this is the js function I use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#photoimg').live('change', function() {
        $("#hd_pic").html('');
        $("#loading").html('<img src="../img/common/loader.gif"/>').fadeIn(250);
        $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
            target: '#hd_pic'  
        }).submit();
    });
});
```

I don't want to output the result to target: '#hd_pic', but I want to call a function. For example, I do it this way in my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ajax/add_url.php",
    data: dataString,
}).done(function(result) {
    myresult(result);
});​
```

I call the function myresult and I use the result of the ajax call. I also want to do this in the ajaxform submit function. Is it possible to do this?

This doesn't work:

```
        $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
        success: myresult(result)
    }).submit();
```

Comment: Sorry to ask, but have you just tried doing it and see what happens?

Comment: Never used ajaxForm.js, so I'm not sure I can help.  But, you should move your code to use `on` instead of `live`.  `live` has been deprecated (jQuery 1.7 I think).

Comment: $('#imageform').ajaxForm(function() {/*stuff*/ }) Where /*stuff*/ is what you want to do after a successful submit.  I'm not sure it will return 'result' but you can give it a try.

Comment: Yes I tried something. See edit of initial post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do:

```
$("#imageform").ajaxForm({
    success: myresult
}).submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *target*, you can use a *success* callback property as one of the [options](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object):

```
$("#imageForm").ajaxForm({
    success: function() {
        // your callback code goes here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

exact syntax you want

```
 $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
        target: '#hd_pic',
        success: function(){/*your code after here*/}
    })
```

[jQuery API: Ajax Options](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: As a side-note in case OP wants to upgrade to 1.8: See deprecation notice half-way through the ajax documentation (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/): `The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.` As far as I know 1.9 will remove them.

Comment: Oh s***! Didn't know! (I usually stick to 1.6 because I have MVS load it automatically and covers most things I need it for.) Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Does that have anything to do with ajaxForm plugin? And in either case the success option isn't being depreciated, only the success method of `jqXHR` objects.

Comment: @KevinB: My comment referred to the answer as it stood before the last edit which contained a plain ajax call. But to answer your question, I don't know for sure. Unless ajaxForm does not use an jqXHR object I would assume it also effects it.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Ah, I'm very sorry, I didn't see the "Edited" notice. Although, i think my comment still stands against the original answer, he wasn't using the `.success` or `.error` methods.